# Dynamic Block - Blocks of type "xxx" are not expected here

Tags: terraform

I try to use a Dynamic block with the following ressource: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/netascode/iosxe/latest/docs/resources/interface_nve

"vnis" have to be dynamic and the  expected result must be like this

```
resource "iosxe_interface_nve" "nve1" {
  device   = var.leaf_name
  name                           = 1
  description                    = "VTEP"
  shutdown                       = false
  host_reachability_protocol_bgp = true
  source_interface_loopback      = 1
  vnis = [
    {
      vni_range            = "10123"
      ingress_replication  = true
    },
    {
      vni_range            = "11234"
      ingress_replication  = true
    }
  ]
}
```

The syntax I imagined is the following one:

```
resource "iosxe_interface_nve" "nve1" {
  device                         = var.leaf_name
  name                           = 1
  description                    = "VTEP"
  shutdown                       = false
  host_reachability_protocol_bgp = true
  source_interface_loopback      = 1
  dynamic "vnis" {
    for_each = var.l2vni
    content {
      vni_range               = each.value["vni"]
      ingress_replication     = true
    }
  }
}
```

I'm stuck with the following error:

```
│ Error: Unsupported block type
│
│   on modules\terraform-iosxe-nve\main.tf line 32, in resource "iosxe_interface_nve" "nve1":
│   32:   dynamic "vnis" {
│
│ Blocks of type "vnis" are not expected here.
```

I wonder if I missed something regarding the dynamic block syntax as soon as it's the first time I need it. Is it possible that dynamic block are not supported in any resource?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to Mark here is the code modified and working as expected.

```
locals {
  l2vni_list  = [
    for key, l2vni in var.l2vni : {
        vni_range               = l2vni.vni
        ingress_replication     = true
    }
  ]
}

resource "iosxe_interface_nve" "nve1" {
  device                         = var.leaf_name
  name                           = 1
  description                    = "VTEP"
  shutdown                       = false
  host_reachability_protocol_bgp = true
  source_interface_loopback      = 1
  vnis = local.l2vni_list
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`vnis` isn't a block, it's a list of objects. Note how `vnis = [` has a  square bracket `[` which indicates a list, not a brace `{`.

You simply need to build a list dynamically, and assign it to the `vnis` attribute of your resource. You could use a `for` [expression](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/expressions/for) for that.

Comment: Thanks a lot Mark, as a consequence i added a new locals to create the list and then just consume it in the ressource. It works perfectly.

Comment: Yeah using `locals` to build the list is the cleanest way to do it.